# How can I tell what partition is Ubuntu

Tags: boot

I am having boot problems. I have launched the Ubuntu Live CD and I can view the contents of my disk partitions. I seems to have other linux installations. How can I tell which one it Ubuntu? (I think the other one is Suze.) I.e. by inspecting files etc rather than booting from one.

Comment: You already installed Ubuntu and try to find which partition belongs to Ubuntu, am i correct?

Comment: @AvinashRaj, Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First mount all the ext4 partitions inside `/media` directory.Then run the below commands.

I assume, you have 3 ext4 partitions,

```
 sudo mkdir /media/part1
 sudo mkdir /media/part2
 sudo mkdir /media/part3
```

Create directories on`/media` to get you partitions mounted.

```
 sudo mount /dev/sdaX /media/part1      
 sudo mount /dev/sdaY /media/part2
 sudo mount /dev/sdaZ /media/part3
```

Mount the partitions on it's corresponding directories.

```
 cat /media/part1/etc/issue | cut -d' ' -f1,2
 cat /media/part2/etc/issue | cut -d' ' -f1,2
 cat /media/part3/etc/issue | cut -d' ' -f1,2
```

Output of any one of the commands from above will give you `Ubuntu xx.xx`. From that you come to know on which partition does  Ubuntu is preinstalled.